# MPMoviePlayerViewController doesn't play m3u8 smooth on iOS7

Tags: ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller, m3u8, adaptive-bitrate

MPMoviePlayerViewController doesn't play smooth on iOS7 a stream with adaptive bitrates.
It has some pauses. Even on iPhone 5, even on a 42mb(12mb real) 3g connection. The stream is composed by 300,150 and 900kbps adaptive bitrates.
Here's how it looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zo9mc8n414wp0c1/Video%2010-10-13%2016%2038%2003.mov

The same stream, on the same type of device, on the same network plays continuously in iOS6

Can you tell where can be the cause of this buffering and what can make it play smoother in iOS7?